# what effect does setting min-height after height: auto do?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the effect of setting min-height css property but also defining height: auto?

```
height: auto;
min-height: 300px;
```

Comment: height:auto is the default value so your are simply setting a min-height (after and before it irrelevant in CSS when talking about properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: auto` is the default value for height, so you'd only need to include it to override a `height` set somewhere else in the stylesheet. For example, you might have:

```
div.box {
  height: 32rem;
}

div.box.special {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 32rem;
}
```

This would have the effect of allowing `<div class="box special"></div>` to expand past its 32rem minimum height if the content required it.